# Explaining the chain rule when using quotient rule.

Tags: derivatives, chain-rule

I have a problem in my WebWorks hw , modeled after  Rogawski ET 3e section 3.7, exercise 35. The problem reads, find the derivative of $(\frac{x+81}{x-81})^{20}$. I know the answer is $-3240 \frac{(x+81)^{19}}{(x-81)^{21}}$, however I don't know how to get that answer. Can someone explain the steps to achieving the answer?

Comment: Are you familiar with these rules (if they do not occur combined) ?

Comment: I know the formulas on a individual level. But when combined I'm confused.

Comment: I misread the expression. : It is $(\frac{x+81}{x-81})^{20}$ , not $\frac{x+81}{(x-81)^{20}}$ , right ?

Comment: The inner derivate is the derivate of $\frac{x+81}{x-81}$

Comment: The outer deivate is $20x^{19}$, where $\frac{x+81}{x-81}$ has to be inserted for $x$, so $20(\frac{x+81}{x-81})^{19}$

Comment: So, the desired derivate is $(\frac{x+81}{x-81})' \times 20(\frac{x+81}{x-81})^{19}$

Comment: The rest should be easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to find the derivative of $$f(x)=\left(\frac{x+81}{x-81}\right)^{20}$$ We must use the chain rule here. Let $u=\dfrac{x+81}{x-81}$ so the function now becomes $$f(u)=u^{20}$$ The derivative of this function is $f'(u)\cdot u'$(definition of chain rule). We know $f'(u)$ to be $20u^{19}$. Now we must multiply by $u'$.
\begin{align*}
u'&=\left(\frac{x+81}{x-81}\right)'\\
&= \frac{x-81-(x+81)}{(x-81)^2} \\
&= -\frac{162}{(x-81)^2}
\end{align*}
So the derivative is 
\begin{align*}
f'(x)&=20u^{19}\cdot -\frac{162}{(x-81)^2}\\
&=-20\left(\frac{x+81}{x-81}\right)^{19}\cdot \frac{162}{(x-81)^2}\\
&=-20\frac{(x+81)^{19}}{(x-81)^{19}}\cdot \frac{162}{(x-81)^2}\\
&= -\frac{3240(x+81)^{19}}{(x-81)^{21}}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

As you expect, you have to apply both the chain rule and the quotient rule. Let's start by using the chain rule to represent $\frac{x+81}{x-81}$ as a function $u(x)$. Then what you are trying to find is, by the chain rule,

$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du} \frac{du}{dx}
$$

Where $y = (\frac{x+81}{x-81})^{20} = u^{20}$.

So, as @Peter showed,

$$
\frac{dy}{du} = 20u^{19} = 20(\frac{x+81}{x-81})^{19}
$$

And all you need to do to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is to multiply that by $\frac{du}{dx}$, which you can find yourself using the quotient rule,

$$
\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx} (\frac{x+81}{x-81})
$$

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much! This was combined with Peter's comment above really helped me understand .

Comment: You're very welcome. Remember that if you ever see something complicated, try breaking it up into simpler parts, and then use the tools you have to solve those simple parts.